# Привет! Столкнулся с проблемой. Выдает ошибку в 20 строке кода

Tags: python

```
    DATABASE = {
    'Серёга': 'Омск',
    'Соня': 'Москва',
    'Миша': 'Москва',
    'Дима': 'Челябинск',
    'Алина': 'Красноярск',
    'Егор': 'Пермь',
    'Коля': 'Красноярск'
}

def process_anfisa(query):
    if query == 'Сколько у меня друзей?':
        count = len(DATABASE)
        return 'У тебя ' + str(count) + ' друзей.'
    # Здесь проверьте, что переменная query равна строке 'Кто все мои друзья?'
    elif query == 'Кто все мои друзья?':  
        friends_string = ''
        # Чтобы получить перечень друзей - 
        # переберите словарь DATABASE в цикле
        for query == 'Кто все мои друзья?': # ЗДЕСЬ ОШИБКА!
            friends_string += friend + ' '     # Добавляйте к переменной friends_string имя друга и пробел
        # Верните строку, составленную из 'Твои друзья: ' и friends_string 
        return('Твои друзья: ' + str(friends_string)) 
    else:
        return '<неизвестный запрос>'

# Не изменяйте следующий код
print('Привет, я Анфиса!')
print(process_anfisa('Сколько у меня друзей?'))
print(process_anfisa('Кто все мои друзья?'))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 20
    for query == 'Кто все мои друзья?':

                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Начни здесь: [ask]

Comment: Естественно выдает. Вы неправильно понимаете схему работу цикла for. Вместо сравнения там должны быть счетчик и контейнер (`for x in y`, для каждого x в y). Почитайте какой-нибудь учебник, там это все объясняется.

Answer (score 1):

[можешь почитать о циклах](https://skillbox.ru/media/code/tsikly-v-python-kak-rabotayut-i-kakie-byvayut/).

```
DATABASE={
 'Серёга': 'Омск',
    'Соня': 'Москва',
    'Миша': 'Москва',
    'Дима': 'Челябинск',
    'Алина': 'Красноярск',
    'Егор': 'Пермь',
    'Коля': 'Красноярск'
}

def process_anfisa(query):
    if query == 'Сколько у меня друзей?':
        count = len(DATABASE)
        return 'У тебя ' + str(count) + ' друзей.'

    # Здесь проверьте, что переменная query равна строке 'Кто все мои друзья?'
    elif query == 'Кто все мои друзья?':
        friends_string = ''
        
        # Чтобы получить перечень друзей -
        # переберите словарь DATABASE в цикле
        for friend in DATABASE: # ЗДЕСЬ БЫЛА ОШИБКА!
        # Добавляйте к переменной friends_string имя друга и пробел
            friends_string += friend + ' '     
        # Верните строку, составленную из 'Твои друзья: ' и friends_string
        return('Твои друзья: ' + str(friends_string))
    else:
        return '<неизвестный запрос>'

# Не изменяйте следующий код
print('Привет, я Анфиса!')
print(process_anfisa('Сколько у меня друзей?'))
print(process_anfisa('Кто все мои друзья?'))
```

---

```
Привет, я Анфиса!
У тебя 7 друзей.
Твои друзья: Серёга Соня Миша Дима Алина Егор Коля
```